# Coordinate system for South and North America together?

Tags: coordinate-system, north-america, south-america

I am working on project where i need south and north america together and i search for the best coordinate system.

I have choosen wgs 1984 but distortion in north part is very big.

Comment: "WGS 1984" is not a coordinate system, but GCS_WGS_1984 is.  I think you'll find that the distortion at the north is the exact same as in in the south (absolute latitude), not that any GCS should ever be evaluated for distortion in Cartesian space.

Comment: @Vince GCS_WGS_1984 is Esri's very idiosyncratic name for WGS 84. We don't even know if the OP is using ArcGIS software!

Comment: komy, what is your purpose for the data? Visualization? Analysis? If analysis, what kind? Try sinusoidal (customize it to have a central meridian/longitude of center around -90) or Goode's Homolosine. Another possibility would be a customized oblique Mercator. Also, what software are you using?